# java Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() and nproc return different values

Tags: java, docker

I'm running a `Java app` inside of a `docker container`, which is restricted to `4 CPU` and the machine on which the `docker container` runs, has `10 CPU`.

When calling `nproc` inside the `docker container`, I get as a result `4`, but when I call `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` I get `10` as result.

- why is this happening? How come does `Java` see all `CPU`?
- is there another way of getting in `Java` the same result asa `nproc`, besides using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nproc")`?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596774/runtime-getruntime-availableprocessors-returning-1-even-though-many-cores-av

Answer (score 1):

According to Ken Sipe (link below) there is a bug in java for showing the wrong no of cpus/cores when using shared cpus (default in docker) instead of cpusets (pinned cpus for a process).

I myself however see the wrong number regardless this setting:

Runtime.availableProcessors(), no docker: 8
in docker I always get 4,

whereas nproc says 1 (when using --cpuset-cpus=0 <- pinned on cpu0)

see https://vimeo.com/138955223