# Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() returning 1 even though many cores available on ECS AWS

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ecs

I am running a task via Docker on AWS's ECS. The task does some calculations which are CPU-bound, which I would like to run in parallel. I start a thread pool with the number of threads specified in `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` which works fine locally on my PC. For some reason, on AWS ECS, this always returns 1, even though there are multiple cores available. Therefore my calculations run serially, and do not utilize the multiple cores.

For example, right now, I have a task running on a "t3.medium" instance which should have 2 cores according to the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/).

When I execute the following code:

```
System.out.println("Java reports " + 
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + " cores");
```

Then the following gets displayed on the log:

```
Java reports 1 cores
```

I do not specify the `cpu` parameter in ECS's task definition. I see that in the list of tasks within the ECS Management Console it has a column for "CPU" which reads 0 for my task. I also notice that in the list of instances (= VMs) it lists "CPU available" as 2048 which presumably has something to do with the fact the VM has 2 cores.

I would like my Java program to see all cores that the VM has to offer. (As would normally be the case when a Java program runs on a computer without Docker).

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks @dokaspar - deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @stdunbar in the comments for pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT: Thanks to @Imran in the comments. If you start lots of threads, they will absolutely be scheduled to multiple cores. This answer is only about getting `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` to return the right value. Many "thread pools" start as many threads as that method returns: it should return the number of cores available.

There seem to be two main solutions, neither of which is ideal:

- Set the `cpu` parameter in the task definition. For example, if you have 2 cores and want to use them both you have to set `"cpu":2048` in the task's definition. This isn't very convenient for two reasons:

  - If you choose a bigger instance, you have to make sure to update this parameter.
  - If you want to have two tasks running simultaneously, both of which can sporadically use all cores for short-term activities, AWS will not schedule two tasks on a 2-core system with `"cpu":2048`. It says the VM is "full" from a CPU perspective. This goes against the timesharing (Unix etc.) philosophy of every task taking what it needs (for example, imagine on a desktop PC, if you run Word and Excel on a dual-core computer, and Windows wouldn't allow you to start any other tasks, on the grounds that Word *might* need all of one core, and Excel *might* do too, so if another program *might* need all the core at the same time, there wouldn't be enough cores.)
- Use the `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=xx` JVM option in JDK 10 onwards, as described [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146115). This isn't convenient because:

  - As above, you have to change the value if you change your instance type.

I wrote a longer blog post describing my findings here: https://www.databasesandlife.com/java-docker-aws-ecs-multicore/

Comment: IMO CPU units are soft limits here. Example:When I give 512 as CPU units in task def and ECS service shows CPU usage in CW is sometimes beyond 100%, 200% etc., Why do you think this happens?. Doesn't this mean my container is using more than half core soft limit I provided which tells timesharing is happening right?. I would think if a given EC2 all cores are filled up by soft limits of all ECS tasks then it says VM is full during deployment only but in reality, the actual runtime usage is that all cores are not occupied unlike hard limits we set on memory. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks @Imran you are absolutely right. I've added an edit in my answer to clarify.

Comment: With `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` parameter `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns the correct value when running in container environment. As far as I know it works in Java 10 and above.